# R, gsub(), replace "." for "," given some conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, gsub

I have data like

```
obs  Var1   
1    36.091  
2    14.678  
3    3.12
```

My problem is that i want to replace `"."` by a `","` with `gsub()`, but not for all the observations, just for the observations that have 3 characters to the right of the dot `(".")`. In this case for observations 1 and 2.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
if ( nchar(something indicating the characters to the right of ".") >= 3){
gsub(".",",",data[,1])
} 
else {}
```

I don't know if it's the correct approach, but i don't figure out another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a lookahead based regex. This would replace dot with comma only if the dot is followed by atleast three characters.

```
> x <- c('36.091', '14.678', '3.12')
> gsub("\\.(?=.{3})", ",", x, perl=T)
[1] "36,091" "14,678" "3.12"
> df <- data.frame(obs=c(1,2,3), Var1=c('36.091', '14.678', '3.12'))
> df$Var1 <- gsub("\\.(?=.{3})", ",", df$Var1, perl=T)
> df
  obs   Var1
1   1 36,091
2   2 14,678
3   3   3.12
```

OR

```
> gsub("\\.(.{3})", ",\\1", x)
[1] "36,091" "14,678" "3.12"
```

If you want to make little more accurate then replace dot present inside the lookahead or capturing group to `\\d`, which matches exactly a digit character.

```
gsub("\\.(?=\\d{3})", ",", x, perl=T)
gsub("\\.(\\d{3})", ",\\1", x)
```

Comment: or `gsub("\\.(?=\\d{3})", ",", x, perl=T)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `strsplit` , but looks messy:

```
gg$Var1<-do.call(rbind,
           lapply(gg$Var1,function(x) 
                    ifelse(
                            nchar(strsplit(x,"\\.")[[1]][2])==3,sub("\\.",",",x),x)))

> gg
  obs   Var1
1   1 36,091
2   2 14,678
3   3   3.12
```